# John the Ripper Installation - make not working

Tags: command-line-interface

I'm trying to install John the Ripper.
According to the docs for installation on [text](https://www.openwall.com/john/doc/INSTALL.shtml), you simply navigate to the src directory in the John the Ripper extracted folder, right?
And then run $ make, right?
But it's not working for me.
Any solutions to complete the installation?

I tried "Makefile" and "makefile."
None worked.